# How can we define a column with padding and just one item doesn't inherit the padding of the column in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, padding

I have a column with many items, and I want to set the padding for the column because all items have the same padding except one of them which doesn't have padding, how can I consider an exception for that specific item? Or is it possible to add an attribute that says don't get your parent padding? I know I can remove padding for column and add one by one, but I want to ask anybody knows that, is there any other way?

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
 Text(text = "Teaser1")

Text(text = "Teaser2")

Text(text = "Teaser3")

Text(text = "Teaser")

Text(text = "Teaser4")

Text(text = "Teaser5")

...

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Modifier.layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).layout(kotlin.Function3)).

I override the width constraint by adding padding for `measure`, and applying the padding offset during `place`.

```kotlin
Text(
    text = "Teaser",
    modifier = Modifier
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val noPaddingConstraints = constraints.copy(
                maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth + (padding * 2).roundToPx()
            ) 
            val placeable = measurable.measure(noPaddingConstraints)
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                placeable.place(x = -padding.roundToPx(), y = 0)
            }
        }
)
```

Comment: Thanks good solution, for my case I came up with the nested column and gave the padding to the nested column, because the exceptional item was the last item and easily solved. But if the exceptional item lays in the middle of the list, I think your solution would be better.

Comment: This doesn't quite align. `roundToPx()` is only available inside `with(LocalDensity.current)` block. The calculated `noPaddingConstraints` add the extra width when measuring, which makes sense. However, specifying X to be negative padding places the placeable outside of those new constraints. I had to subtract some magic number of pixels from startPadding to pass as X to get it to align, which does not make the solution deterministic.

Comment: @Vas it aligns just right in the author case, yours may be different. maybe your view has some extra padding, or aligned inside the view? Here's the [sample](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/842a80fc2051ecfc7d0d9fd324a74942) where everything is aligned correctly. with `Modifier.layout` you're making computations on `MeasureScope`, which implements `Density` interface - so you don't need  `LocalDensity` here.

Comment: @PhilDukhov Thanks for your answer! I'm trying to adapt this to work with a LazyRow nested inside a Column, and I can get it to work, but not in all cases. In the sample code you linked to, if you change the Text to something like (                text = "Teaser 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0",
) it highlights the problem. (Any string that is equal to or longer than the width of your Column.) Adding maxLines = 2 with a long string will also show the issue. Have you run into this in your use of this solution?

Comment: @Tom inside `LazyRow` your `constraint.maxWidth` is equal to infinity, since it's a scroll view. You can apply my modifier to the `LazyRow` itself, and add `contentPadding`

Comment: @PhilDukhov Thanks for the reply. I've added your solution to a LazyRow + contentPadding, and I can get it to work if I change to .place(x=0,y=0), but I still run into the same problem that exists in your linked [sample](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/842a80fc2051ecfc7d0d9fd324a74942). If I could get your sample code working with short strings and long strings, I think that would solve my problem.

Comment: @Tom please create a separate question with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @PhilDukhov 's solution, I've made one minor change that might make this a little more general purpose. I was having problems with longer strings (see my example code below), or any other View that had a measured width greater than constraint.maxWidth. In that scenario, this line:
`placeable.place(x = -padding.roundToPx(), y = 0)`
would place the string partially off screen.

Here is my updated solution:

```
private fun Modifier.overrideParentHorizontalPadding(parentHorizontalPadding: Dp) =
    layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val padding = (parentHorizontalPadding).roundToPx()
        val noPaddingConstraints = constraints.copy(
            // Make the new maxWidth = maxWidth + twice the horizontal padding of the parent
            maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth + (padding * 2)
        )
        val placeable = measurable.measure(noPaddingConstraints)
        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            if (placeable.width > constraints.maxWidth) {
                placeable.place(x = 0, y = 0)
            } else {
                placeable.place(x = -padding, y = 0)
            }
        }
    }

@Preview(name = "Test Padding Override")
@Composable
private fun PaddingOverridePreview() {
    val padding = 20.dp

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Gray)
            .padding(horizontal = padding)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Gray)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text("Normal")
        Text(
            text = "Override this",
            modifier = Modifier
                .overrideParentHorizontalPadding(padding)
        )
        Text(
            maxLines = 1,
            text = "And this 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 012",
            modifier = Modifier
                .overrideParentHorizontalPadding(padding)
        )
        Text("Normal")
    }
}
```